# Is there any way to migrate Liferay to sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

We want to migrate the possibilities of our Liferay to SharePoint Integration. I am looking for a high-level understanding of any architectural diagram if any

looking for an architecture diagram or any ways to migrate from LifeRay to Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the Liferay you use has an export feature.
The version of Liferay they have has an export feature that uses some metadata to create the folder structure on a local disk and then we’re using ShareGate to upload and tag based on the folders.
Or there must be an option to migrate the data with jquery, json, Ajax or other JavaScript, Wikipedia says so.

You can try with visual studio to build a solution on your own, hence there is no migration tool so far.

And I find a post may give you some inspiration.
https://liferay.dev/ask/questions/portal/document-library-migration-from-liferay-to-sharepoint-1